# What is the use of "Private" classes in C++

Tags: c++

I'm studying one C++ open source project code which has a class defined as below:

```
class MarginStacker : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    friend class MarginStackerPrivate;

public:
    ...
};
```

MarginStackerPrivate class is defined (and implemented at the same time) in the same source file that has implementation of MarginStacker class, and it looks like below:

```
class MarginStackerPrivate : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QMap<QodeEdit::Margin, AbstractMargin*> margins;
    MarginStacker* stacker = nullptr;
    QHBoxLayout* layout = nullptr;
    CodeEditor* editor = nullptr;
    QTimer* updateLayoutTimer = nullptr;

MarginStackerPrivate( MarginStacker* _stacker )
    : QObject( _stacker ),
        stacker( _stacker ),
        layout( new QHBoxLayout( stacker ) ),
        editor( 0 ),
        updateLayoutTimer( new QTimer( this ) )
{
    Q_ASSERT( stacker );

    // more implementation code here
    ...
};
```

In this open source project this approach has been used in several other places. What exactly is the advantage of this? Is there a name for this kind of approach in C++?

Comment: It's a way to hide implementation. Qt also makes use of the [PIMPL idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) (see https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer)

Comment: Well I am no expert either, but it seems to me that this is supposed to hide some of the implementation details to give a cleaner interface for the use of the class.

Comment: @Steve: This is not exactly the PIMPL (pointer to implementation) idiom because MarginStacker does not contain a pointer to MarginStackerPrivate. This friend class approach serves the same purpose as far as encapsulation is concerned, but I doubt that it works as a 'compiler firewall'.

Comment: @FrankPuffer I agree. I didn't have a good example for this case, though, so I pointed to PIMPL as an example of something similar. This is Qt code, and they do use this technique as well.